# Multi-server setup for Windows clients with Ubuntu servers

Tags: windows, samba, ldap

I need a simple server setup for a client, and have used Ubuntu for them for some years as a simple combined login server and fileserver.

We now need to change to using two separate servers. so was wondering what the process was to have a setup where:

- Users log in to their Win7 and WinVista machines using domain accounts hosted on Ubuntu
- They can map a drive to a share on an Ubuntu server without logging on again

What I think I need is a couple of pointers to the types of tech I'm looking for here - I'm currently only using pure SAMBA for the PDC behaviour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set up a second Samba server that is configured as a domain member. You will need to join it to the PDC using the "net join" command. After the second machine is joined to the domain the workstations should be able to access it without re-entering credentials (assuming they log on to the domain through the PDC).

See also http://www.samba.org/samba/docs/man/Samba-HOWTO-Collection/domain-member.html